# Keyboard not open in Landscape mode in android Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, keyboard

In Emulator Landscape mode keyboard not opened.In my app i have EditText to get value.In portrait mode when clicking EditTExt the keypad opened properly. when switching to landscape mode(Ctrl+F12) the keyboard not opening when clicking the EditText.Can any one tell me how to open the keyboard in landscape mode in android emulator?

This is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OptionScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest file.

Comment: @Siddharth i have posted the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In your `<activity>` in manifest file, add :

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi
```

Hope this helps.